# How to pass `time` from a fluentd event to Elasticsearch and Kibana properly?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, fluentd

### tl;dr;

How in fluentd add `time` from the event to Elasticsearch (so it's usable as "Timestamp field" in Data view in Kibana)?

I was able to add `time` and `tag` like that:

```
<filter grabt.listener.**>
    @type record_transformer
    <record>
        tag ${tag}
        time ${time}
    </record>
</filter>
```

But `time` is in string format (`2022-04-17T17:17:31+00:00`) and can not be used as a Timestamp field.

### Full question

I am running a Python script inside a Docker container using `--log-driver=fluentd`.

I have a basic Fluentd, Elasticsearch, Kibana setup (almost one to one from official documentation): https://github.com/jkulak/efk-stack.

My Python script is logging using `structlog` and I see json logs in the stdout as expected.

All my logs are going to Elasticsearch and I can see them in Kibana. So far so good.

In Kibana, when defining new Data View, I am not able to select a Timestamp field as it is disabled (please see my screen below).

My fluentd configuration is like:

```
<source>
  @type forward
  port 24224
</source>

<filter grabt.listener.**>
  @type parser
  key_name "$.log"
  hash_value_field "log"
  reserve_data true
  <parse>
    @type json
    time_key time
    keep_time_key true
  </parse>
</filter>

<filter grabt.listener.**>
    @type record_transformer
    <record>
        tag ${tag}
        time ${time} # <---- what to do here?
    </record>
</filter>
```

How to include in the record, time in any format that would be stored in Elasticsearch and then considered a proper date/time, timestamp value by Kibana, so I can sort my records by time?

**Update**

As suggested in the comment below you can find logs I see and what I would like to see.

My Python script logs JSON to stdout:

```
{"logger": "get_albums.py", "name": "Heiken & Kenshin", "spotify_id": "3bIU4wnnl3J1J0w2dCciL5", "object": "artist", "event": "Processing artist"}
```

When Fluentd is saving it to a file `@type file` then I see that `time` and `tag` is saved together with my log data (event) - as it should ([fluentd event structure](https://docs.fluentd.org/quickstart/life-of-a-fluentd-event#event-structure)):

```
2022-04-17T17:17:31+00:00   grabt.listener  {"container_name":"/get-albums","source":"stdout","log":"{\"logger\": \"get_albums.py\", \"name\": \"Heiken & Kenshin\", \"spotify_id\": \"3bIU4wnnl3J1J0w2dCciL5\", \"object\": \"artist\", \"event\": \"\\ud83d\\udc68\\ud83c\\udffd\\u200d\\ud83c\\udfa4 Processing\"}\r","container_id":"f16ff942df2bb20dcf5dd7f338fd245dcfbc3b5ba1d15c89306074d2befdadae"}
```

But when saved to Elasticsearch (and displayed in Kibana) it misses the time field:

```
log.event:Processing artist log.object artist container_id:f16ff942df2bb20dcf5dd7f338fd245dcfbc3b5ba1d15c89306074d2befdadae container_name:/get-albums log.logger:get_albums.py log.name:Heiken & Kenshin log.spotify_id:0tCtGc5vt29zFZp6KXzN50 source:stdout tag:grabt.listener _id:3bIU4wnnl3J1J0w2dCciL5 _index:grabtracksp-listeners _score:5.855
```

It is missing the `time` field (or any kind of time/timestamp field) that can be used to timeline the events in Kibana.

I could add the time in Python to the log. I could add the timestamp field using the `fluentd-plugin-elascticsearch`. But I am wondering how to do it in Fluentd with it's plugins. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: I was able to insert the @timestamp field using official `fluent-plugin-elasticsearch` that has a flag for that. But the above question still stands, how to do it on fluentd level.

Comment: Please add the input and output logs in your question.

Comment: Have you tried `timestamp ${time}`?

Comment: Also, how did you verify that the log received at ES/Kibana contained `time` key in there?

Comment: Can you be more specific? Did I try it where exactly?
I verified that fluentd event has a `time` field by logging it to a file - and I saw it there.

Comment: I'm referring to your first `<filter>` section. Instead of `time ${time}`, did you try to use some other key e.g. `timestamp`? By verifying the log, I meant to ask whether you verified the log received at ES. What did it look like i.e. all its fields?

Comment: I guess you are referring to my second `<filter>` section then. And `time` there is only a key that is showing up in the logs. So changing it to `timestamp` would only change the key. In ES, time was stored as string `2022-04-17T17:17:31+00:00`.